# Route snapping with Python OSRM

Tags: python, osrm

I want to do route snapping with OSRM, almost exactly what this person did: https://www.jamesrcroft.com/2015/06/snapping-gps-tracks-to-roads/. However, instead of javascript, I want to use Python, so I installed python-osrm (https://github.com/ustroetz/python-osrm) and now I want to be able to load my own .osrm file with routes in it along with coordinates and timestamps to snap to a road and determine which route was taken. I read the documentation for the python-osrm package on the github page, but I don't see anything that accepts a .osrm, coordinates, and timestamps and returns a snapped route. I wanted to use this package because I thought it would be easier than trying to figure out the osrm project http api. Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I'm trying to use the package myself, it doesn't take `.osrm` files rather it works with GPS lat/lon (points if routing, list of tuples if using `match`), I keep on getting `400 Bad Request` errors though.